# How to assign a value in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
list4 = [[10, 20, 40], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
for i in range(len(list4)):
    list4[i][-1] = 100
print(list4)
```

It works, but how could i set a value in list comprehension

`list5 = [i for i in range(len(list4))  list4[i][-1] = 100]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following list comprehension gives same operation as the for loop:

```
list5 = [arr[:-1]+[100] for arr in list4]
```